# How To Change a tuple into an int?

Tags: python, pandas

I am also new to python and I am already learning the module Pandas, and one of the following questions ask: which of the items is the most expensive? I am using this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv
here's the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv"
url_read=pd.read_csv(url, sep="\t")
print("csv file: \n", url_read)
group_url=url_read.groupby("item_price")
for i in group_url:
    print(i)
print("the most expensive item ordered is: \n", int(i))
```

and then it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-29a99cd89e7e> in <module>
----> 1 print("the most expensive item ordered is: \n", int(i))

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

I know there may already be answers but their code didn't really help me. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `i`? You didn't initialize it in your code and all we have to go on is the traceback with the error telling us that it's a tuple.

Comment: What is the value of `i`? You don't show us where you assign it in the code snippet.

Comment: One guess would be a stray `,` at the end of the line assigning to `i`, for example: `i = "123",`

Comment: oh, I didn't give you the code

Comment: well i is a tuple that I am trying to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv"
url_read=pd.read_csv(url, sep="\t")
print(f"the most expensive item ordered is: {url_read.loc[url_read['item_price'].str.strip(',|$').astype(float).div(url_read['quantity']).idxmax(), 'item_name']}")
```

Output:

```
the most expensive item ordered is: Steak Salad Bowl
```

Details:

- idxmax returns the index of the maxium value found
- 'div' divides
- .str is a [string
  accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods)
- strip removed characters form a string in this case using a regex for
  , or $.
- astype changes the dtype of the series to float

Comment: I don't know for some reason I am getting error trying to read this url using pandas.

Comment: thanks, it works but I want to know how every func works

Comment: if you can, please include that

Comment: why do we need to have a | before the $ sign?

Comment: We may have not needed the '$' just habit when I see price.

Comment: also, why do we need to divide the quantity?

Comment: I assumed that the price per item was if you had an item valued at $10, then the price per item if you brought 2 would be $20. and $30 for three items bought.  You should verify in  your data, if that is price per unit item or price per item purchased at that time.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh okay

Answer (score 0):

Converting a tuple to a list is simple.

```
myTuple = ('a', 'b', 'c')
myList = List(myTuple)
```

This will not solve your issue though. And you generally don't want to convert a pandas tuple into a list. Pandas uses tuples because tuples are more memory efficient and faster than lists, because tuples are immutable and have low overhead.

Remember that Pandas was designed for data science environments, where people typically deal with millions of rows. Your dataset is minuscule so it's not going to give any issues if it's results are casted into a list, but it could slow things down if it were larger.

This works but it's not so elegant.

```
#filter the df
#This line creates a new DF which only contains the row with the highest price in the DF.
filteredDf = df[(df.PRICE = df['PRICE'].max())]
#Select the column.
#This overwrites the DF so that it only includes the product name, since it was already filtered, this product is the one with the highest price.
filteredDf = filteredDF['PRODUCT_NAME']
#This accesses the value by its numerical index (it's what iloc does), since there's only 1 column and 1 row, the indeces are 0 and 0.
mostExpensiveItem = filteredDf.iloc[0,0]


print('Most expensive Item is ', mostExpensiveItem)
```

Comment: thanks, but can't you just do df.PRICE.max()?

Comment: From the way you worded your question I thought you meant you wanted to display the name of the item, not its price. If you only want to display the highest price then yes, you can use the code you wrote.

Comment: oh okay, next time I ask, I'll remember that tip.